# Modify tuples inside a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, format, tuples

I'm trying to make a bunch of tuples show only one decimal using a for loop.

```
Van = (500.3736434, 43.834434)
Vbn = (300.2321313, 64)
Vcn = (250.43513241, 12)

listap = [Van, Vbn, Vcn]

for i in range(0,len(listap)):
    listap[i] = tuple([float("{0:.1f}".format(n)) for n in listap[i]])
```

The desired result is only displayed when I print a specific index in the list, like `print(listap[0])`for example. Anyway I can get the reduced tuples without using the list? for example, doing

```
print(Van)
>>> (500.4, 43.8)
```

Comment: Python tuples are immutable - you cannot modify them in place

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new tuple.

```
new_list = []
for old_tuple in listap:
    new_tuple = tuple([round(i, 1) for i in old_tuple])
    new_list.append(new_tuple)
print(new_list)
# [(500.4, 43.8), (300.2, 64), (250.4, 12)]
```

But, if you just want to print them as a list, you can do:

```
for old_tuple in listap:
    print([round(i, 1) for i in old_tuple])
```

which outputs

```
[500.4, 43.8]
[300.2, 64]
[250.4, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python tuples are immutable - you cannot modify them in place. What you could do is, instead to convert into the desired format and rename the converted variables to the same name -

```py
Van, Vbn, Vcn = [tuple([float("{0:.1f}".format(n)) for n in el]) for el in listap]
print(Van)
# (500.4, 43.8)
```